# Unable to get the correct location of a view on android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the location of `textView` using the `getX()` and `getY()` functions.

As seen from the code below, `textView.getX()` and `textView.getY()` used in `onCreate()` method returns a value `0.0`.

But `textView.getX()` and `textView.getY()` used in `checkCoord` returns `32.0` for both `getX` and `getY` functions.

I am unable to understand this change in values for `getX()` and `getY()`. Kindly help. Code is as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView textView;
        Button bt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                   bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                   System.out.println("Inside onCreate textView X : " + textView.getX());
                   System.out.println("Inside onCreate textView Y : " + textView.getY());

                   bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   checkCoord(v);

                   }
                   });

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
       }

       public void checkCoord(View view) {

            System.out.println("Inside checkCoord textView X : " + textView.getX());
            System.out.println("Inside checkCoord textView Y : " + textView.getY());

       }

}
```

Comment: need position of textview??

Comment: `View`s will have x,y position after `onLayout()` is called. and you are getting correct values in `onCreate()` as drawing is still not performed...

Answer (score 1):

The difference has to do with the lifecycle of the activity see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Basically in onCreate your view hasn't actually been drawn on the screen yet so there are no values to return. But when you call the method through the onClickListener the view has been drawn so there are values to return